# XamlParseException caused by an InvalidOperationException on page's State when using external components

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

As said in the title, I've got this exception when I use the Coding4Fun ColorPicker in my XAML.

I've tried removing all the references to this component and the page loads fine.

Here's the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <phone:Pivot Grid.Row="0">
                <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="Background">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>   
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <c4f:ColorPicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Opacity:"/>
                        <Slider Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource CustomSlider}"/>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="Foreground">
                <Grid>
                    <c4f:ColorPicker/>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            </phone:Pivot>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CustomSettings}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

EDIT:
I've added a `BindableAppBar` before using the ColorPicker, and now the exception moved to the AppBar's line.

Seems like it throws the exception when I use external libraries!

EDIT 2:

Seems like that the exception depends on the `ApplicationState` but I'm not using it wrong!

```
public Settings()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.GetType();
        }
    }


    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        // Get the model from app's state
        Model = (BasePluginModel)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["active"];
    }
```

The exception is thrown in the `InitializeComponent()` method and, navigating to the `State` property of the page, it says:

> -State '((Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage)(this)).State' generated an exception 'System.InvalidOperationException'  System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary {System.InvalidOperationException}

Expanding the object, the `Message` is:

> Message "You can only use State between OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom" string

Now, from the code you can see that I'm using the state only in the right event. Even commenting that lines lead to the same error. What's wrong with this code?

EDIT 3:

Those are the namespaces that I'm using. Everything was downloaded from NuGet.

```
xmlns:c4f="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:bar="clr-namespace:BindableApplicationBar;assembly=BindableApplicationBar"
```

Comment: Is there any inner exception?

Comment: No, the inner exception is set to null. I've edited the first message as the error appeared also with another component

Comment: What is the minimum needed to recreate this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get what's the "minimum" that you're talking about! :(

Comment: What code does {Binding CustomSettings} bind to?

Comment: Could you write the namespace you are using for the external components?

Comment: Done. I've also removed the `{Binding CustomSettings}` fyi

Comment: Hey @StepTNT, if you can create a repro project that I can debug against and upload it to https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create.  This will let me verify if it is the coding4fun Toolkit.

Comment: I'll do it asap, but I don't think this is something related to Coding4Fun Toolkit. I've got this problem even in a page with just the MS Toolkit (nothing else in my namespace!)

Comment: @ClintRutkas : I'm now sure that this is not related to our Toolkit. I have the same problem in a simple project when I use the `System.Windows.Interactivity` namespace